# How to use typescript in reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, reduce

My code:

```js
const calculateSum = <T>(array: T[], key: string): number => {
  const total = array.reduce<number>((accumulator, object: T) => {
    return accumulator + object[key];
  }, 0);

  return total;
};

type TProjectServiceList = {
  id: number;
  sum: number;
};

const services = [
  {id: 1, sum: 78.09},
  {id: 2, sum: 105.09},
  {id: 3, sum: 8.45}
]

const totalSum = calculateSum<TProjectServiceList>(services, 'sum');
```

I got Typescript error:

> object[key] - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

How to make this function with typescript generics?

Comment: TS doesn't know that `key` is a key of `T`, nor that `T[typeof key]` is `number`.  You can tell it so like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBYvbw). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in the definition of `calculateSum` is the type of T mentioned. So the compiler is obviously unaware of the type of the values of keys of `T`. Hence, the error.

You can specify that `T` extends a particular type and make life easy for the compiler.

Given that you are trying to add these values I would like to assume that the values are all of type `number`. Here is a solution for now:

```
const calculateSum = <T extends { [id : string] : number}>(array: T[], key: string): number => {
  const total = array.reduce<number>((accumulator, obj: T) => {
    return accumulator + obj[key];
  }, 0);

  return total;
};

type TProjectServiceList = {
  id: number;
  sum: number;
};

const services = [
  {id: 1, sum: 78.09},
  {id: 2, sum: 105.09},
  {id: 3, sum: 8.45}
]

const totalSum = calculateSum<TProjectServiceList>(services, 'sum');
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAbYBXR8oFMDKKC2MAvDADwAqAfABTwBOt8AngFwxkDaAugDQwDWmFjGi0AlmADmASlZh8AI0y0iFGAG8AUDDjhoMKCChIiMOg0YA6WpgAmKYJhJy8i2tRrBUeNBhC1eIPIAVqxkUirqWtow1lAotGCmnvg+BsoA1DCBQewCjJwA3FEAvrwADFJFUbHxiQZGiEXFVVCMAA6YbAAKtCBBmMBQ2EoAbqIOADKiesSa2qI2sgpKRdoQ+EsuKxrNGhqgkLAQo+OYECbsUWoLrACMvOt4rADsABwWZQCcpVc3MABMDw2MFuZQArB9vtxfosYABmIFPGDvAAsYOKGk4ewOenqSFwBGICGQqRw+HIPT6AyGJ0m0yg1GOtDGDggvAA5I92ZUgA)